# Extract excel ranges into a dataframe in python

Tags: python, sql, excel, dataframe

I have a working excel sheet that does not contain any tables. Instead it has multiple sections of data. I want to extract certain ranges of cells from this sheet and create a new data source that can be used to create Power BI reports.

Examples of the ranges are:

```
    range1 = ws['A5':'N7']
    range2 = ws['A12':'N13']
    range3 = ws['A17':'N20']
    range4 = ws['A33':'N35']
    range5 = ws['A41':'N42']
```

When I print the values of these ranges using Python and openpyxl I get a long list of values which I would like to transform into a new dataframe with custom column headers.

How do I transform that list into a table that I can then either export to an excel or into a sql database?

Thank you

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions. Don't forget to include your current SQL query attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use `pandas.read_excel` as documented [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html). Note the `usecols`, `skiprows`, and `nrows` to select the ranges. Simply call it multiple times to access different ranges.

Subsequently, I'd use `pandas.to_excel` (and other `to_...` functions) to export the dataframe to the appropriate format.

Personally, I only use openpyxl directly when I need to optimize performance, or when I can't install pandas.

Comment: I've switched to pandas, thank you for the advice. I'm having trouble calling skiprows multiple times. Are you able to provide some example code of how you would do that? Anything would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: You'd need to paste your code for me to help you. Could you be re-using a file object? Then you'd need to rewind the file before trying again, or creating a new file object.